# Using Tkinter Python 2.7: Wait for a button to be pressed and use the returned value as a variable

Tags: python, button, input, tkinter

I have been looking for hours and haven't found anything that does this. Maybe it doesn't exist, but I thought I would ask.

I am new to `Tkinter`. I wanted to make a button that pretty much lets the user choose two buttons and then I will perform a function with that button.

I simplified it to this.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class simpleapp_tk(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, command=self.OnButtonClick1, text="Take",width=15)
        self.button1.grid(column=1,row=9,columnspan=2)
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self, command=self.OnButtonClick2, text="Apples",width=15)
        self.button2.grid(column=3,row=9,columnspan=2)
        self.button3 = tk.Button(self, command=self.OnButtonClick3, text="Bananas",width=7)
        self.button3.grid(column=5,row=9,columnspan=1)

    def OnButtonClick1(self):
        #at this point the program will wait for either Button Apples or
        #Bananas to be pressed and assign it to the variable value
        value = buttonValue
        self.randomFunction(value)
        return
    def OnButtonClick2(self):
        return  "Apples"
    def OnButtonClick3(self):
        return "Bananas"

app = simpleapp_tk()
app.title('my application')
app.mainloop()
```

So there would be some other `randomFunction` in `simpleapp_tk` that does something given an input, but that's unimportant.

Does something like this exist that waits for the user to click a button and then stores what is returned by clicking that button into a variable? Ideally I would then be able to do this for multiple variables.

I would wait for user to click a button store that as the first variable, then wait for the user to click a second button then store that as the second variable then perform a function using both of those variables.

Comment: Don't try to `return` things to `Button`s. Instead, save the data to a variable, e.g. `self.food = set()` in the `initialize()` and `self.food.add('Apples')` in `OnButtonClick2()`.

Comment: That's an interesting way. I didn't think of that. I'll try that, but the thing is, I don't want the value to be added to the set until after self.button1 is clicked. Maybe I will have a conditional that is made True when self.button1 is clicked. Thank you, I will try this out.

Comment: You don't have to have another conditional to track whether the button has been clicked. Just put whatever you want the button to do into its callback function, and it'll only happen when the button is clicked (unless you call that function in other ways, in which case you should separate what needs to be separated).

Comment: `command=self.OnButtonClick(10*(i-1)+(j-1))` assigns the _returned value_ of `self.OnButtonClick(10*(i-1)+(j-1))` to that button's callback. Unless that function returns another function (it probably doesn't), that's not what you want. You might want to rethink your code structure and attempt to simplify it, because it doesn't sound like it's doing you any favors.

Comment: Yes, that is what I ended up doing. I had to rethink and I used some variation on your first comment and what Bryan suggested. I didn't know how to deactivate buttons, so I ended up making a conditional and saying if that condition was on then it would return None when the buttons I don't want pressed are pressed. So when you press the first button you set a condition to true so that when you press the second button you enable storing of the return in a variable. It was more of a for fun project rather than something for a grade, so it didn't need to be perfect, just functional. Thank you both

Comment: Use the [Tkinterbook on Effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) to learn about disabling buttons and much, much more.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you don't make a GUI wait since it is already in a perpetual state of waiting. After you click the first button, the GUI is already waiting for you to do something else.

If you want to force the user to click things in a specific order, the common solution is to disable everything but what they can click on at the moment. When they click, you can disable the first button and enable the second, and so on.

It's sometimes necessary to keep a tiny statement machine around, but often just a couple of variables is all you need.

In your case you can just keep track of what has been clicked on with a variable. A dictionary is perhaps the easiest way:

```
clicked = {1: False, 2: False, 3: False}
```

`OnButtonClick1` would set `clicked[1]` to `True`, diasable button 1 and enable button 2, and so on.